# Node/Express.js : Can\'t set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a small node & express.js application. 
I found in my `app.get('/lastName/:lastName',(req,res) =>{...});`
If I use:

```
res.render('employeeList',{data:employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName)});
```

It always conflicts with `res.format({...});`
It gave me an error:

```
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

When I use them separately,  in http://localhost:3000/lastName/Smith I can get the correct view. If I only use `res.format({...});` I also can get correct api feedback through:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost:3000/lastName/Smith"
```

However, I cannot use them at the same time, which is conflicted with assignment requirement.
Can someone give me some clues? Thank you so much! Please see the code below:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const _= require('underscore');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const employees = require('./employeeModule.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars',
    handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// GET request to the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/addEmployee',(req,res) => {
    res.render('newEmployee');
});
//..........................Problem here.........................
app.get('/id/:id',(req,res)=>{
    let paramsId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    //res.render('employeeList',{data:employees.lookupById(paramsId)});
    //res.send(employees.lookupById(paramsId));
    res.format({
        'application/json': () => {
            res.json(employees.lookupById(paramsId));
        },
        'application/xml': () => {
            let employeeXml =
                '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<employees>\n' +
                employees.lookupById(paramsId).map((e)=>{
                    return ' <employee id="' + e.id + '">' +
                        '<firstName>' + e.firstName + '</firstName>'+ '<lastName>' + e.lastName + '</lastName>' + '</employee>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</employees>\n';
            res.type('application/xml');
            res.send(employeeXml);
        },
        'text/html': () => {
            let employeeHtml = '<ul>\n' +
                employees.lookupById(paramsId).map((e)=>{
                    return ' <li>' + e.id + ' - ' +
                        e.firstName + ' - ' + e.lastName+'</li>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</ul>\n';

            res.type('text/html');
            res.send(employeeHtml);
        },
        'text/plain': () => {
            let employeeText =
                employees.lookupById(paramsId).map((e)=>{
                    return e.id + ': ' + e.firstName + e.lastName;
                }).join('\n') + '\n';
            res.type('text/plain');
            res.send(employeeText);
        },
        'default': () => {
            res.status(404);
            res.send("<b>404 - Not Found</b>");
        }
    });

});
//..........................Problem here.........................
app.get('/lastName/:lastName',(req,res) =>{
    let paramsLastName  = req.params.lastName;
    res.render('employeeList',{data:employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName)});
    res.format({
        'application/json': () => {
            res.json(employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName));
        },
        'application/xml': () => {
            let employeeXml =
                '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<employees>\n' +
                employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName).map((e)=>{
                    return ' <employee id="' + e.id + '">' +
                        '<firstName>' + e.firstName + '</firstName>'+ '<lastName>' + e.lastName + '</lastName>' + '</employee>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</employees>\n';
            res.type('application/xml');
            res.send(employeeXml);
        },
        'text/html': () => {
            let employeeHtml = '<ul>\n' +
                employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName).map((e)=>{
                    return ' <li>' + e.id + ' - ' +
                        e.firstName + ' - ' + e.lastName+'</li>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</ul>\n';

            res.type('text/html');
            res.send(employeeHtml);
        },
        'text/plain': () => {
            let employeeText =
                employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName).map((e)=>{
                    return e.id + ': ' + e.firstName + e.lastName;
                }).join('\n') + '\n';
            res.type('text/plain');
            res.send(employeeText);
        },
        'default': () => {
            res.status(404);
            res.send("<b>404 - Not Found</b>");
        }
    });
});

app.post('/data',function (req,res) {
    let bodyData = req.body;
    let bodyDataFirstName  = bodyData.firstName;
    let bodyDataLastName  = bodyData.lastName;
    employees.addEmployee(bodyDataFirstName,bodyDataLastName);
    res.redirect('/lastName/'+bodyDataLastName);
})
app.get('/api/employees',(req,res) =>{
    res.format({
        'application/json': () => {
            res.json(employees.getAllEmployee());
        },
        'application/xml': () => {
            let employeeXml =
                '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<employees>\n' +
                employees.getAllEmployee().map((e)=>{
                    return ' <employee id="' + e.id + '">' +
                        e.firstName + e.lastName + '</employee>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</employees>\n';
            res.type('application/xml');
            res.send(employeeXml);
        },
        'text/html': () => {
            let employeeHtml = '<ul>\n' +
                employees.getAllEmployee().map((e)=>{
                    return ' <li>' + e.id + ' - ' +
                        e.firstName + ' - ' + e.lastName+'</li>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</ul>\n';

            res.type('text/html');
            res.send(employeeHtml);
        },
        'text/plain': () => {
            let employeeText =
                employees.getAllEmployee().map((e)=>{
                    return e.id + ': ' + e.firstName + e.lastName;
                }).join('\n') + '\n';
            res.type('text/plain');
            res.send(employeeText);
        },
        'default': () => {
            res.status(404);
            res.send("<b>404 - Not Found</b>");
        }
    });
});


app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('http://localhost:3000');
});


/*
 curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:text/html" "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:text/plain"   "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 */
/*
 curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/api/employees"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost:3000/lastName/Smith"
 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost:3000/lastName/Smith"

 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost:3000/id/2"
 curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" "http://localhost:3000/id/2"

 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a response twice to the same request.

The error message you are receiving is caused when your code tries to send two responses to the same request.  So, you have to remove all the places in your code where that can happen.

In your `app.get('/lastName/:lastName', ...)` handler, you are first calling `res.render()` and then later trying to do `res.send()`.  But, the way you're calling `res.render()`, the response to the request is already sent by that call so you can't then again call `res.send()` or `res.json()` because that will try to send another response to the same request and that will trigger the error message you see.

If you're trying to just render the HTML and then use that rendered HTML as part of the response that is sent later, then you need to use a different form of `res.render()` where you pass it a callback and it calls you back with the HTML that you can then send later.

See the doc for [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) to understand how to use the callback option to fetch the HTML without sending it as a response so that you can later use it when sending the response you want to send.

The general scheme is like this:

```
app.get('/lastName/:lastName',(req,res) =>{
    res.render(file, options, function(err, html) {
        if (!err) {
            // response has not been sent yet
            // put your res.format() code here and use the above html argument
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is clearly a problem in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a response twice.

your `res.render` renders `employeeList` and then sends it as a response. afterwards you're trying to send another response, which is not allowed and does not correspond the request-response cycle.

In addition, you're using a templating engine to render your page:

```
let paramsLastName  = req.params.lastName;
res.render('employeeList',{data:employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName)});
```

and then you try doing it manually here:

```
'text/html': () => {
            let employeeHtml = '<ul>\n' +
                employees.lookupById(paramsId).map((e)=>{
                    return ' <li>' + e.id + ' - ' +
                        e.firstName + ' - ' + e.lastName+'</li>';
                }).join('\n') + '\n</ul>\n';

            res.type('text/html');
            res.send(employeeHtml);
        }
```

you can either call res.render inside of `res.format` under `'text/html'`,
or outside of the `res.format` block using `app.render` - which renders the html but doesn't send it as a response.

```
app.render('index', {data:employees.lookupByLastName(paramsLastName)}, function(err, result) {
    // result is the resulting html from rendering your data.
    // save it to some variable to use later or do something with it here
});
```